# Please help me get javac to work in windows 7 pro

Tags: java, javac

I am starting to teach myself Java programming and found a great book called *Java: A Beginner's Guide, Sixth Edition* by Herbert Schildt.  I really like it.

I am also doing the udacity.com classes which uses the BlueJ ide. I want to install javac and run and compile a java source code file from Windows 7 cmd prompt, but I can't get javac to work!

Java JDK1.8.0_60 is currently installed in C:\Program Files\Java.  I went to environment variables under system and only have a 'Path' variable.  I don't have a 'PATH' one.  How do I get javac to work?

Comment: Path is actually the one you're searching for.

Comment: @John did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add the Java Bin to the Path Environment Variable As (Assuming JDK1.8.0_60 is the correct folder),

```
C:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.8.0_60\bin
```

When you edit the path variable, go to the end of the value and look for a `;` . If you have a semicolon. just add the above value and use another `;` to end that variable value. Do save/ apply/ ok,  Close existing command prompts and them start a new one try `java -version`

Edit:

Can you go in to this  `C:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.8.0_60\bin` folder and see if you have a file called javac?

Comment: java -version in command prompt produces: 

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-h27)
and more

but javac still produces:
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

this is annoying.  I want javac to work!  Or to at least get eclipse to compile and run.  Please help.  thanks.

Comment: @JohnKooz can you follow my new edit and check if it exists?